# gsl_complex causing memory overflow

Tags: c++, windows, complex-numbers, gsl

I'm seeing some odd behaviour from the GNU Science Library complex number functions. The issue is demonstrated in the following snippet:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <gsl/gsl_complex.h>
#include <gsl/gsl_complex_math.h>

int main() {
    double realNumber = 1.0;
    gsl_complex complexNumber;

    GSL_SET_COMPLEX(&complexNumber, 1.0, 1.0);

    printf("%p: ", &realNumber);
    printf("%f\n", realNumber);

    gsl_complex_add(complexNumber,complexNumber);

    printf("%p: ", &realNumber);
    printf("%f\n", realNumber);

    return 0;
}
```

The output is

```
0061FF18: 1.000000
0061FF1C: 0.000000
```

The function `gsl_complex_add` changes the value of the pointer to `realNumber` such that it no longer points to `realNumber`, even though `realNumber` doesn't seemed to be linked to the function in any way. I assume this is due to some sort of overflow.

The problem does not occur if I use `std::cout` instead of `printf`; I imagine this is due to the compiler.

If I declare `realNumber` as `static` the problem does not occur.

If I declare `realNumber` as `const`, `printf("%p: ", &realNumber);` returns an incorrect value, but `printf("%f\n", realNumber);` returns the correct one.

Is this a bug or am I doing something I shouldn't be?

I am using the g++ compiler (version 6.3.0) on a Windows machine.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: is it debug, release or both configurations?

Comment: The default release mode I believe (no compiler flags other than the relevant libraries).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After further investigation I realised that I was using a very old version of GSL. The described behaviour disappeared after updating to the latest stable version.